# Setting [cluster] must not be empty

Tags: elasticsearch

Version - 7.0.0

While I am trying to start elasticsearch from the command line using below command getting an error "*setting [cluster] must not be empty*"

**Command**

./bin/elasticsearch -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your operating system or are you using some special shell?

On a Mac `./bin/elasticsearch -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_1` is working fine.

Reading `setting [cluster] must not be empty` I assume that your shell is having issues with the dot and just runs `./bin/elasticsearch -Ecluster`. What you could try is to quote the values passed to -E, so try `./bin/elasticsearch -E"cluster.name=my_cluster" -E"node.name=node_1"`. At least on a Mac this is working fine (as well).